# Why isn't “api” method available in Gradle 4.4/Java plugin, when “implementation” is?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

I'm using AS 3.1, trying to be a good programmer and clear the "compile is obsolete" warnings. But I desire this particular .jar to expose Guava as an API. Other projects (e.g. CloudServerApplication) need Guava, too. But when I use the `api` keyword, instead of `compile` or `implementation`, I get this:

```
>gradlew FrameManager:build

> Configure project :CloudServerApplication
4.4

> Configure project :FrameManager
4.4


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\FrameManager\app\build.gradle' line: 16

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':FrameManager'.
> Could not find method api() for arguments [com.google.guava:guava:14+] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
```

I tried Googling the error, but did not find anything useful. Not really sure where to look next.

My build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

println GradleVersion.current().getVersion()

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.json:json:20160212'
    api 'com.google.guava:guava:14+'   //<-- This used to be "compile"
}
```

Answer (score 61, accepted):

> Could not find method api() for arguments

The `java` plugin doesn't contain this method.

You **have to use** this plugin:

```
apply plugin: 'java-library'
```

As you can check in the [official doc](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_library_plugin.html):

> The key difference between the standard Java plugin and the Java Library plugin is that the latter introduces the concept of an API exposed to consumers. A library is a Java component meant to be consumed by other components. It’s a very common use case in multi-project builds, but also as soon as you have external dependencies.
>
> **The plugin exposes two configurations that can be used to declare dependencies: api and implementation**.